# Javascript fade in/out not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

I am working on a little javascript gallery that displays a number of differenty images, and fades in and out. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the fade in properly working.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this?
This is my code so far:

```
//This goes in the head of the html file:
<script type="text/javascript">
var imageCount = 4;
var image = new Array(imageCount);
image [1] = "slideshow/testimg1.jpg"
image [2] = "slideshow/testimg2.jpg"
image [3] = "slideshow/testimg1.jpg"
image [4] = "slideshow/testimg2.jpg"
</script>

//This goes in the body of the html file
<img width="760" height="260" name="slide">
<script type="text/javascript">
var step = 1;
document.images.slide.style.opacity = 1;
function NextImage()
{
    //Change image
    document.images.slide.src = image [step];
    //Change step
    if (step < imageCount)
        step++;
    else
        step = 1;
    FadeIn();
}
function FadeIn()
{
    if (document.images.slide.style.opacity < 1)
    {
        //Increase opacity
        document.images.slide.style.opacity += 0.05;
        setTimeout("FadeIn()", 20);
    }
    else
    {
        //Set opacity to 1, fade out
        document.images.slide.style.opacity = 1;
        setTimeout("FadeOut()", 4000);
    }
}
function FadeOut()
{
    if (document.images.slide.style.opacity > 0.05)
    {
        //Reduce opacity
        document.images.slide.style.opacity -= 0.05;
        setTimeout("FadeOut()", 20);
    }
    else
    {
        //Set opacity to 0.5, change the image
        document.images.slide.style.opacity = 0.05;
        NextImage();
    }
}
NextImage();
</script>
```

The idea is that is swithes between the NextImage, FadeIn and FadeOut functions.
I have everything working except for the fades, because it whenever I test it it goes like this:

Load image, fade out, load second image, freeze.

I hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

~Luca.

EDIT:
This fixed it:

```
//Increase opacity
var x = parseFloat(document.images.slide.style.opacity) + 0.05;
document.images.slide.style.opacity = x;
setTimeout(FadeIn, 20);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well and perhaps a live example on jsfiddle or something

Comment: The basic idea is to copy & paste code, do not understand it/screw it, go to SO, start asking questions ... right?

Comment: The code's actually freezing because of the call stack either the events need to be cleared simultaneously or use of jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
setTimeout("FadeIn()", 20);
```

to

```
setTimeout(FadeIn, 20);
```

and see if that helps (and the other setTimeout functions as well).

**EDIT/Addition**:
The document.images.slide.style.opacity += 0.05; is not actually incrementing. Try the following modification:

```
//Increase opacity
var x = parseFloat(document.images.slide.style.opacity);
x += 0.05;
document.images.slide.style.opacity = x;
setTimeout(FadeIn, 20);
```

Comment: The code's actually freezing because of the call stack either the events need to be cleared simultaneously or use of jquery

Comment: setTimeout can be thought of as run once and forget (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout). Maybe you are thinking of setInterval (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Comment: I know that but the relative number of event that is to be stored in the even que exceeds and we get an exception. Thats y code freezes :) i know my fiddle link is not working i just wanted to show the reason with the alert box. Thats y i proposed a jquery examplw in the link. Its just not giving an answer its more than that the reason needs to be known as to y it is freezing to prevent similar use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle.

Actually wat is happening is the event stack where the set time out function saves the events to be executed after a particular interval is getting overflown :)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDfeH/1/)

```
try{


   var imageCount = 4;
var image = new Array(imageCount);
image [1] = "http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2009/06/01/article-0-05144F3C000005DC-317_468x387.jpg";
image [2] = "http://images.theage.com.au/ftage/ffximage/kaka_narrowweb__300x323,2.jpg";
image [3] = "http://ricardokakaonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/istoe.com_.br-kaka.jpg";
image [4] = "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1226/1366784050_d697d3cde3.jpg";
var step = 1;
document.images.slide.style.opacity = 1;
function NextImage()
{
    //Change image
    document.images.slide.src = image [step];
    //Change step
    if (step < imageCount)
        step++;
    else
        step = 1;
    FadeIn();
}
function FadeIn()
{
    if (document.images.slide.style.opacity < 1)
    {
        //Increase opacity
        document.images.slide.style.opacity += 0.05;

        setTimeout(FadeIn(), 200);
    }
    else
    {
        //Set opacity to 1, fade out

        document.images.slide.style.opacity = 1;
        setTimeout(FadeOut(), 2000);
    }
}
function FadeOut()
{
    if (document.images.slide.style.opacity > 0.05)
    {
        //Reduce opacity
        document.images.slide.style.opacity -= 0.05;
        setTimeout(FadeOut(), 200);
    }
    else
    {

        //Set opacity to 0.5, change the image
        document.images.slide.style.opacity = 0.05;
        NextImage();
    }
}
NextImage();
}catch(e){
alert(e)
}
```

try using jquery to give fade in fade out .. I just added a try catch block to see Why it is freezing.

Heres a link for fade in fade out using javascript [fade in out](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/01/javascript-fade-in-out/)

Comment: I know it does not work . I just wanted all to clear the idea with the alert that what is happening and why it is freezing. You can edit that and try using a button click. No worries if he has written a string instead of a method still the code will freeze. :)

Comment: The crypt error message is because of setTimeout(FadeIn(), 200); where is should be setTimeout(FadeIn, 200);

Comment: Thanks for the correction . :) . But do you know why then the freezing is happening ?